# Custom image KeyBoard IOS 9 Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, ios9, custom-keyboard

i'm trying to develop a custom keyboard with only images, all the tutorials or examples i found was for swift 1 and IOS8 so when i tried to build it into Xcode 7.1, it exploded..

Someone knows a tutorial or an example of an app like this?

Comment: just upgrade to latest swift syntax...pretty easy

Comment: oh very helpful, but as there are API changes, even if i upgrade it with the assistant, the code has errors....